# Matching 3D views of resistor on pads with stackup table

Tags: pcb-design

I would like to match the visual 3D photo shown below and the 2D with the stackup. From 3D there is a resistor on pads. I cannot see from the stackup in the end the 3D form. Is there some intuition I could use?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This link will take you to an excellent (and official) Altium resource: forum.live.altium.com

Comment: @lub2354, your question doesn't mention the software name. At least add the Altium tag, of that's what it is.

Comment: The stackup table just shows the makeup of the PC board itself - it doesn't show the components that you intend to place on the board.